# Maven repository for EJB 3.1 API

Tags: java, maven-2, ejb-3.1

What Maven repository can I use for EJB 3.1 API dependency?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This dependency from central worked.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Note that this API has some [specific issues with removed code](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/trouble_with_crippled_java_ee)